# jquery filter "a" tag with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a problem with my code:

```js
$('.tag').filter(function(){ return this.href.toLowerCase().match(/tagged\/large$/);}).hide();

$('.tag').filter(function(){ return this.href.toLowerCase().match(/tagged\/_large$/);}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="tag" href="/tagged/laRge">large</a>
```

I want to hide on my page the "a" tags which include "tagged/large" or "tagged/_large" in the href attribute no matter if it's written in big or small letters.
Now I have both possible links in separate scripts and I want both in one so I want to ask if you know a way to combine these two scripts?

Comment: Try `/tagged\/_?large$/gi` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the lower dash optional in your regex by adding a question mark:

```
$('.tag').filter(function(){ return this.href.toLowerCase().match(/tagged\/_?large$/);}).hide();
```

Comment: I used this one but I excluded the .toLowerCase() and added an "i" at the end of the regex so the code is shorter. Thank you!

Comment: Good improvement! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it will work fine if you want an  tag with href with _large to large be hidden.

```
$('a').each(function(e){
    if($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("large")>-1)
      {
            $(this).hide()
      }
})
```

Below is the complete html page

```
<html>
            <head>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <a class="tag" href="/tagged/laRge">large</a>
                <a class="tag" href="/tagged/_laRge">_large</a>
                <a class="tag" href="test/">test link</a>
            </body>
            <script>
            $('a').each(function(e){
                if($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("large")>-1)
                    {
                        $(this).hide()
                    }
                })
            </script>
</html>
```

> This hides the 1st two links but not the 3rd link